# How to read in a dat file and than save a manipulated dat file

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a .dat [file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nSpay_puwT6jGQHExwb30hCLqq6eP-73/view?usp=sharing) which I read in with the following code:

```
i = pd.read_csv(path, sep="\s+", encoding="cp1252", nrows=0)
meta = list(i.columns.values)
data = pd.read_csv(path, sep="\s+", encoding="cp1252", skiprows=3)
```

I then want to manipulate it with pandas (for example remove half of the rows) and then save it again as dat file just like the old one. I guess it is important to get the delimiter and encoding of the old dat file so I can save the new one with these parameters.

Comment: can you put a snippet of the dat file or share it

Comment: added the dat file

Comment: can you add the first few lines of it here? it's a huge file

Comment: Is this multiple datasets (tables) in one file, or just one, huge, dataset? Looks like this is all for "8000 Hz".